Running web server with docker get broken dag
I have installed apache airflow on VS code and import in python file successfully, but when i compose and browse the web server, i get the error broken dag: No module named 'airflow.operators.python'. What i need to fix, here is my yml file
version: 'latest'
services:
redis:
image: 'redis:5.0.5'
postgres:
    image: postgres:14.0
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
        - POSTGRES_DB=airflow


webserver:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - postgres
        - redis
    environment:
        - LOAD_EX=n
        - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
        - EXECUTOR=Celery

    volumes:
        - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags

    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    command: webserver
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 30s
        retries: 3

flower:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - redis
    environment:
        - EXECUTOR=Celery

    ports:
        - "5555:5555"
    command: flower

scheduler:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - webserver
    volumes:
        - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags

    environment:
        - LOAD_EX=n
        - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
        - EXECUTOR=Celery

    command: scheduler

worker:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - scheduler
    volumes:
        - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags

    environment:
        - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
        - EXECUTOR=Celery

    command: worker


Puckel docker-airflow use an older airflow version, 1.10 i guess.
Try to use the official Apache image: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#fetching-docker-compose-yaml
Does ur DAGs folder has any DAG ?

Thanks for ur answer and yes, i have dags file and also i have fixed and run successfully
